# Unexpected Behavior When Appending Multiple List Inside function in PyQt GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am experiencing strange behavior while trying to append to two different lists from inside of the same function.

```
x = 0
y = 0
list_1 = []
list_2 = []

def append_function(self):
    self.x += 1
    self.y += 1
    self.list_1.append(self.x)
    self.list_2.append(self.y)        
    print self.list_1
    print self.list_2
```

The output that I would expect from running the function once is:

```
[1]
[1]
```

If I ran twice I would expect:

```
[1,2]
[1,2]
```

The actual output that I get from running the function once is:

> [1]

When I run the function twice I get:

```
[1]
[1,2]
```

Every time I run the function the first list lags behind. This only happens when I run the code inside of the GUI class. Otherwise it runs as expected. Does anyone know why this happens or know a workaround?

Here's the entire program:

```
#imports
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

import ui_sof_test  #Gui File
import sys

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):


    def run(self):                
        pass
class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_sof_test.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):        
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()        
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.start()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.append_function)
    x = 0
    y = 0
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []

    def append_function(self):
        self.x += 1
        self.y += 1
        self.list_1.append(self.x)
        self.list_2.append(self.y)        
        print self.list_1
        print self.list_2

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #                                        Worker Thread(s) Setup                                  #
    ##################################################################################################

    def start(self):  
        self.setupWorker()


    def setupWorker(self):
        self.work = Worker()
        #self.work.mcx.connect(self.setxy,QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        #self.work.mcy.connect(self.move_cur_lifty,QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        if not self.work.isRunning():#if the thread has not been started let's kick it off
            self.work.start()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  # A new instance of QApplication
    form = Gui()  # We set the form to be our ExampleApp (design)
    form.show()  # Show the form
    app.exec_()  # and execute the. app

if __name__ == '__main__':  # if we're running file directly and not importing it
    main()  # run the main function
```

Comment: The way you've defined the Gui class [assuming the indentation is correct as posted], `list_1` and `list_2` are _class attributes_ (essentially class globals), not _instance attributes_.  This might account for the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I need them to be class globals. Is this not acceptable?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you'll need tight coordination among your worker threads so that two threads don't try to write to the globals simultaneously.

Comment: @John I thought about that but the example above is producing the same behavior even though the worker thread isn't doing anything.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe something else is going on then.  You said when you run the program once, you get output of `[1]`.  But there are _two_ print statements in `append_function()` -- how is this possible?  Can you try modifying the code so that each print statement contains something unique (i.e. `print 'list_1 is: %s' % list_1`) and then see which print statement is showing up?

Comment: _The actual output that I get from running the function once is: `[1]`_ I don't see how this is possible, given `append_function()` contains _two_ print statements.  I think you've not posted the correct code.

Comment: @john i just noticed something else that is interesting. If I run the function once I still get [1]. If I then close the GUI window, the function finishes running other print statement is executed.

Comment: Strange.  Where is the `print` output appearing?  In a console window?

Comment: Yes. I am running the program from inside of the Spyder IDE and the print statement is executed in the IDE's console.

Comment: Perhaps your IDE is doing some sort of output buffering?  Maybe you could try displaying the output in a popup window instead of a plain `print`.

Comment: It was the Spyder's Iron Python console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unique to the Iron Python console in the Spyder IDE. Running the code in another python terminal produces the expected result.